# Wake computer via Wake On Lan using Arduino/Raspberry Pi

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, wake-on-lan, arduino

Is it possible to use Wake On Lan (WOL) without going through the router? Using an Arduino or Raspberry Pi connected to the internet to manually (through the ethernet port) tell the computer to wake up? The picture below represents what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

Since the router tells the computer to wake up *through* the ethernet-cable, wouldn't it be possible to re-create what happens without including the WiFi router?

Comment: Yes. WOL is just "FF FF FF FF FF FF" followed by the mac of the target network adapter repeating 16 times, so an Arduino or RPI would be perfectly suited just by sending the magic packet with the MAC for the connected device.

Comment: But as said, we'd like to send it directly through the cable, not as a magic packet. The Arduino / Raspberry intercepts the Ethernet cable, and should send the signal through the wire (if possible)

Comment: You can still use the arduino or raspberry pi to send the magic packet. There are literally dozens of samples of exactly this on Google. The point of having the passthru network ports is so you can do things like this or munge data as it passes through.

Comment: That's not what I want to do though :) As stated, I want to send it through the pins "manually".

Comment: Exactly how do you perceive a difference? The source is the arduino/rpi, the destination is an ethernet port connected to it. The WOL protocol is reliant on a magic packet that is formed in a specific structure with the FFx6+MAC*16.. Even if there's no switch/router/modem involved, the magic packet can still be sent across the eth port. Even if there's no routing or addressing going on. The magic packet doesn't rely upon the IP of the target device, it relies on the MAC address, and broadcasting the magic packet across the port will work just fine.

Comment: I'm not sure we're completely understanding each other here. I posted a new question, containing all the info I have on the subject, and a more clear question; https://superuser.com/questions/1388179/send-wake-on-lan-wol-request-manually-through-the-ethernet-cable-using-an-ardu :)